# To use struct or not for same primitives

Tags: c, struct

I wonder when its neccesary to use a struct in c?

More precisely - if I have the following primitive datatypes - what is the best solution

1) to just declare and initialize these primitive datatypes in the actual function

2) to declare these variables in a struct and then initialize these in the actual function.

I am making a program where I need to calculate certain values for the cumulative distributed function (CDF) and one way to do this is to make a polynomial approx. The following values are needed to do this:

```
k = 1 / (1 + yx)
y = 0.33267
a1 = 0.4361836
a2 = -0.1201676
a3 = 0.9372980
```

I have declared and initialized these values as follows:

```
    double k = 0;
    double y = 0.2316419;
    double a1 = 0.319381530;
    double a2 = -0.356563782;
    double a3 = 1.781477937;
```

My question may sound a bit silly - its all about if I should put these values in a struct or not?

that is in the headerfile:

```
 struct cdf {
  double k;
  double y;
  double a1;
  double a2;
  double a3;
};

 typedef struct cdf Cdf;
```

Then I can obtain these datatypes via

```
 cdf.k
```

for instance

So - does it make my program more readable if I bunch variables that belongs together in a struct or is it completely unnecessary? All of the primitives are of type **double**
so why should one put those in a struct?

Comment: Yes it does make sense than few #defines..

Answer (score 2):

A struct would be advantageous when:

- ... the same set of parameters is used in several places. In that case defining them as a `struct` saves typing.
- ... the set of parameters needs to get passed around from one place to another. In that case the `struct` neatly groups the values together and makes it clear that all the values belong together and form a coherent chunk of data.

If these values are only used in one place, I personally would not bother creating a `struct`, although it won't hurt anything to do so (it won't make your code any slower or anything).

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you want to pass the bunch of variables to a function, or get them returned from a function, a struct makes things much easier for you. Besides, it's easier to have a struct if you want to declare more than one set of variables.

If your program consists of a 20 line main() and nothing else, that probably doesn't matter. If your program consists of 20000 lines, it does matter a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If they are not related then it might be confusing to have a struct, but you should make them all `static const double` or do the same for your struct.  I would not use a struct here.

If you need to pass the same several values together to different functions, a struct is usefull

If you are going to use the same several values in different structures, a struct is usefull

If you need the same several values to be arrays with the same dimension, it is more usefull to have an array of struct rather than many separate arrays.  This may also improve performance due to locality, everything is close in memory and will cause fewer cache loads

If you are going to be writing and reading the same several values to a file, a struct is usefull

if it makes the code easier to read, a struct is usefull